# Avoid closing Shiny browser when an error occurs

Tags: r, shiny

When we do an app in shiny we know that:

1 - If you have a function in the `server` part and that function returns an error the browser crash/close and the user doesn't know what is going on.

2 - If you have a function that returns an error inside another render function, for example `renderDataTable`, the error is shown in the app instead of showing the table.

Knowing the previous 2 points I try to put the functions that are potential to return an error inside the render functions. Doing that the user can see the error.

For example, if I want to show some tables coming from databases and I have a simple query like:

```
dbGetQuery(con, 
            statement = glue_sql("SELECT DISTINCT COLUMN1 FROM TABLE1", .con = con)
```

and `COLUMN1` doesn't exist, then the function will rise an error. If I have that function inside the `renderDataTable`, then the user can see that something is going wrong with the query. If it is just inside `server` then the browser will close.

The problem is that in some situations I can't put the query inside `renderDataTable`. What is the approach that we can follow in order to show the error and avoid the crash of the browser?

Thanks

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You could catch the error with `trycatch` and display it with `showNotification`. I've illustrated this with the Old Faithful Geyser shiny example and added in the trycatch so the app does not crash:

```
library(shiny)

ui <- fluidPage(

    titlePanel("Old Faithful Geyser Data"),


    sidebarLayout(
        sidebarPanel(
            sliderInput("bins",
                        "Number of bins:",
                        min = 1,
                        max = 50,
                        value = 30)
        ),

        # Show a plot of the generated distribution
        mainPanel(
           plotOutput("distPlot")
        )
    )
)

server <- function(input, output) {

###
#CATCHING THE ERROR IN A NOTIFICATION
###
    tryCatch({
        x1 <- DBI::dbGetQuery(con,
                         statement = glue_sql("SELECT DISTINCT COLUMN1 FROM TABLE1", .con = con))
    },
    warning = function(warn){
        showNotification(paste0(warn), type = 'warning')
    },
    error = function(err){
        showNotification(paste0(err), type = 'err')
    })


    output$distPlot <- renderPlot({
        x    <- faithful[, 2]
        bins <- seq(min(x), max(x), length.out = input$bins + 1)

        hist(x, breaks = bins, col = 'darkgray', border = 'white')
    })
}

shinyApp(ui = ui, server = server)
```

[image]
[image]

Comment: Thanks Chris, I was going in the same direction. With the `showNotification` it looks good.

Comment: how is trycatch outside any reactive context?